# How can I switch windows by swiping right or left?

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I'm trying to do the same thing that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> does.
I'm using a Gnome extension called "[Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/)". I have configured up and down swipe to change Workspaces. How can I switch windows by swiping right or left?

Comment: I use ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/. Is this the extension you are referring to?

Comment: @Rayleigh yes this one.